# How do I mount a docker data volume outside of the docker root folder?

Tags: docker

I'm using the command:

`docker run --name <containername> -v /home/folder/uploads:/uploads -p 80:8080 -p 3000:3000 --link mongo:mongo -d image:latest`

I'm expecting to have a local copy of the /uploads folder from my running container inside my /home/folder/uploads for backup and persistence purposes. I store user uploaded files there.But when I check the  /home/folder/uploads folder after uploading some files it's still empty.

I don't have the rights to access the root docker directory directly to see if I have something there , that's why I have to bind the volume somwhere on my host where I have access.

Comment: You should have access to `/uploads` as it's inside container.  Please see documentation https://docs.docker.com/v1.7/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems about how to mount volumes.

Comment: @Saleem yeah , you were right , I checked my dockerfile and realised my workdir with my app was on another path inside the container, thanks!